# css sprite navigation layout issues

Tags: css, sprite

I have a navigation grid, that I want to create rollovers for, using sprites. Thanks to other tips on the site, I managed to get started.

[You can check the code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/)

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li class="button_1"><a href="#" title="Go to the this page">Button text</a></li>
<li class="button_2"><a href="#" title="Go to the this page">Button text</a></li>
<li class="button_3"><a href="#" title="Go to the this page">Button text</a></li>
<li class="button_4"><a href="#" title="Go to the this page">Button text</a></li>
<li class="button_5"><a href="#" title="Go to the this page">Button text</a></li>
</ul>


#navigation{
display: block;
width: 907px;
height: 296px;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/WbDp9lf.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}

#navigation li{
display: block;
float: left;
}

#navigation li a{
display: block;
height:296px;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#navigation li a:hover,
#navigation li a.on{
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/WbDp9lf.jpg);
}

#navigation li.button_1 a {width:175px; background-position:0px 0px;}
#navigation li.button_1 a:hover {background-position:0px -296px;}
/*
```

The problem is - the navigation is two rows of icons. How can I control that only one box is being changed. Currently is works only changing vertical groups.

[checking my jsfiddle will show it better i think.](http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/)

thanks!

Comment: you do not have 2 rows, you have only 5 LIs in a row

Comment: I think you have to read more about sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/2/

i removed a lot of unusefull css... the remaining (good) one is

```
#navigation {
    display: block;
    width: 907px;
    height: 296px;
}
#navigation li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    height:148px;
    width: 181px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/WbDp9lf.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
#navigation li a:hover {
    background-position:0px -296px;
}
```

to make you work, you need a sprite with only 1 read and 1 gray rectagle
set `width` / `height` to the normal `li a` display and with  `background-position:0px 0px` you see only the red rectangle... on hover move the background uppper... thats all

Comment: Hi Florin, many thanks! That is what I want, except that my grid does look like this: http://i.imgur.com/WbDp9lf.jpg I have two rows of icons in the nav. Is that possible with this technique?

Comment: or, would I be better off making two seperate nav images/codes, 1 per line?

Comment: oh, brilliant, I just extended the html to include 10 links - and your solution worked for that as well (see http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/3/ ) Thanks!

Comment: you want each red rectangle to have a different image?

Comment: ops... no... while the highlighting is great - when i introduce the real graphics - this is only repeating the first red box. In reality, every box is a different picture. So, each button or box will require its own positioning > and thats the tricky bit for me :(

Comment: you must add for each LI different css declarations, where the background is moved up/down/left/right ... give me the real image... or modify the red squares image and put a number on each square... then i will help you with another jsfiddle script

Comment: very kind Florin. The new link is http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/5/ and the grid can be seen here http://i.imgur.com/uNa5Wac.jpg. Very Rough, but you get the idea.

Comment: (i didnt line the text numbers up, but doesn't matter for this test)

Comment: here is the solve: http://jsfiddle.net/ahyv7/6/ ... you should read more about sprites though

Comment: wow, thanks. I wish I could give gold or something :) It is appreciated for sure - and I will try to spend time reading up on this!